# Unknown distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{400}$ is a random sample from given distribution with median of m ($P(X_i \le m)=0.5$). Calculate $P(X_{220:400} \le m)$.

How to calculate that? I am lost with this question.
$X_{220:400}$ means that we have 400 observations arranged in an ascending order and we are choosing observation numbered 220.

Comment: Since this is sorted (the order statistics), this event is equivalent to at least $220$ sample is less than or equal to $m$

Comment: I do not think i know how to proceed with this information.

Comment: Toss a fair coin $400$ times. What is the probability we get $220$ or more heads? Unpleasant to do by hand, lots of software will do it. Before software one would use a normal approximation. Maybe you are expected to do so.

Comment: So it will be like $P(S_{400} \ge 220)$? Where S stands for sum of all 400 observations? But what then?

Comment: Not $S_n$, but success if an observation is $\le$ to the median, failure otherwise. We want the probability of $220$ or more successes. Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rephrasing of the answers given in the comments, but note that the definition (in some sense, "purpose") of the median $m$ is so that there is a 50% chance that the random variable assumes a value lower than m.

This is where the analogy with tossing the fair coin 400 times comes in.

Therefore, each event "$X_i \le m$" is just a Bernoulli trial with probability 1/2. We have 400 such events, each is independent, so we have the sum of 400 independent Bernoulli trials.

Such a sum is binomially distributed. Use the binomial distribution (or better yet, since n=400 is so large, the normal approximation to the binomial distribution) to calculate the probability.

Comment: See for example here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/normal_distribution/normal_approx.html

Comment: One reason I think normal approximation is expected is that the variance $np(1-p)$ is the simple number $100$.